# Any source of recycled / second-life PV panels in Ireland?

Tags: solarmeitheal

Does anyone know of any source of recycled / second-life PV panels in Ireland ?
I have a idea for a pathway to reuse panels but I'm missing the original source.
Many panels that are rejected from solar PV farms can be repaired, even if not to 100% rated power and could re-enter production .